# How can I convert a JTS-Geometry into an AWT-Shape?

Tags: java, geometry, awt, shapes, jts

Is it possible to convert a `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry` (or a subclass of it) into a class that implements `java.awt.Shape`? Which library or method can I use to achieve that goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to:

http://lists.jump-project.org/pipermail/jts-devel/2007-May/001954.html

There's a class:

```
com.vividsolutions.jump.workbench.ui.renderer.java2D.Java2DConverter
```

which can do it?

Answer (score 9):

Also have a look at [ShapeWriter](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/javadoc/index.html?com/vividsolutions/jts/awt/ShapeWriter.html) provided by the JTS library. I used the following code snipped to convert jts geometry objects into an awt shape.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.awt.ShapeWriter;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.LineString;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon;

public class Paint extends JPanel{
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        Coordinate[] coords  = new Coordinate[] {new Coordinate(400, 0),  new Coordinate(200, 200),  new Coordinate(400, 400), new Coordinate(600, 200), new Coordinate(400, 0) };
        Polygon polygon = new GeometryFactory().createPolygon(coords);

        LineString ls = new GeometryFactory().createLineString(new Coordinate[] {new Coordinate(20, 20),  new Coordinate(200, 20)});

        ShapeWriter sw = new ShapeWriter();
        Shape polyShape = sw.toShape(polygon);
        Shape linShape = sw.toShape(ls);

        ((Graphics2D) g).draw(polyShape);
        ((Graphics2D) g).draw(linShape);


    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().add(new Paint());
        f.setSize(700, 700);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Edit: The result looks like this image [image: Visualization of jts geometry objects in awt]

Comment: Probably a stupid question. Why are there five coordinates for the square? ;-)

Comment: No worries. I think a Polygon has to start and end by the same coordinate. Therefore the first and last are the same